# Efficient ways/ tools for mysql db cloning

Tags: mysql, bash, centos

I have an ERP that is requesting instances of e-commerce to be created.
These instances are basically clones of the master on a same server.

So I have master DB (currently a dump file) and master code gz.

Through various scripts clone is created and installed.

Everything else is fast except db import from dump.
Plus when there is a request for, say, 50 instances simultaneously, it isn't realistic to import all these databases.

The question is:
**Is there any other efficient tool to import a database other then mysql db < file.sql?**
Any binary formats?

The only solution I can think about is to use a script to create 100 db clones in advance one buy one, and then when 50 new db's are requested, just rename existing clones.

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate the database on the fly without exporting to a file and importing back, this will eliminate parsing a .SQL dump file back to mysql:

```
mysqldbcopy --source=root:root@localhost \
      --destination=root:root@localhost world:world_clone
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/utils-task-clone-db.html